# Showing that $(l'\Sigma l)\chi_p^2 = (l'S l)\frac{(n-1)p}{n-p} F_{p,n-p}$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis

Let $X_1,\cdots X_n$ be i.i.d. $N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$. I have that when $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are unknown that the Scheffe type method gives $(1-\alpha)100$% confidence intervals for all linear combinations $l'\mu$, $l\in\mathbb{R}^p$ as

$$l'\mu: l'\bar{X}\pm \sqrt{c_{\alpha}}s(l'\bar{X})$$

where $c_{\alpha}=\frac{(n-1)p}{n-p}F(1-\alpha;p,n-p)$ and $s(l'\bar{X})=\sqrt{\frac{l'Sl}{n}}$

I also have already proved that a $100(1−\alpha)$% confidence ellipsoid for $\mu$ is given by

$$A=\left\{\mu\in\mathbb{R}^p:n(\bar{X}−\mu)'\Sigma^{-1}(\bar{X}−\mu)\leq\chi^2(1−\alpha;p)\right\}$$

> I'm tasked with showing that when $\Sigma$ is known, the Scheffe  type 
>   simultaneous  $100(1−\alpha)$%  confidence  intervals  for  all 
>   linear combinations $l'\mu$, $l\in\mathbb{R}^p$ are given by
>
> $$l′\mu:l′ \bar{X}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}(l′\Sigma
>  l)\chi^2(1−\alpha;p)}$$

My idea was to try to equate these two confidence intervals. We have that

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}(l'\Sigma l)\chi_p^2}=\sqrt{\frac{(n-1)p}{n-p} F_{p,n-p}\cdot\frac{1}{n}(l'Sl)}$$

or equivalently that

$$(l'\Sigma l)\chi_p^2 = (l'S l)\frac{(n-1)p}{n-p} F_{p,n-p}$$

Since $E(S)=\Sigma$ all we must show is that

$$\chi_p^2 = \frac{(n-1)p}{n-p} F_{p,n-p}$$

(Is this an appropriate step?)

I know that if $U\sim\chi_p^2$ and $V\sim\chi_q^2$ then $\frac{U/p}{V/q}\sim F_{p,q}$ but I'm not sure how or if this applies.

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be appreciated.